# How to power a 6-12v Piezo siren from an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, transistors, mosfet, piezo, siren

We are trying to power a Piezo siren, which requires 6-12v, from an Arduino, which only outputs up to 5v. We are planning on using an external 9v battery to power the Piezo siren, although we do not know how to set this up.

[How to power a 6-14v piezo from an Arduino?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77149/how-to-power-a-6-14v-piezo-from-an-arduino)

We have a MOSFET IRF510 transistor instead of the 2n7000. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The IRF510 isn't a good MOSFET to drive direct from an Arduino - the on resistance is quite high at 5V \$V_{GS}\$.  You should look for one of the IRLxxx series since they are meant for switching at logic levels.

Comment: I drive my piezo sirens directly from the Nano pins.  No need for any extra circuitry.  Here is the one I use:  http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-ATW-PS-101-Piezo-6V-to-12V-DC-Mini-Siren-Fast-Warble-Alarm-Sound-Intensity/161388601047

Answer (score 1):

Both the IRF510 and the 2N7000 are N-channel MOSFETS. You can use the exact same circuit described in the link that you included and it should work fine. Note that the second circuit (one on the right) is the better circuit to utilize.

Do note, however, that not all transistors are created equally. But, the threshold voltages and other characteristics between these two are similar enough that you probably won't notice too much of a difference.